# Java RMI using Tunnelling - an exception

Tags: java, ssh, rmi, putty

This question became very long as we went through debugging steps. I will leave those for any future users who have problems with this, but a short version is here:

**Short version**

Using putty, instead of using "Dynamic" which means that it uses SOCKS, you should use "local" to connect to the SSH server.

See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/272754/what-is-the-difference-between-local-remote-dynamic-ssh-tunneling

Changing this fixed the exception which was:

```
    java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at TMAClient.main(Client.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
```

The second problem was that objects were not using the correct port for exporting. This needed changing to use super(1099) in the constructors for objects which extended UnicastRemoteObject.

**Long version**

I seem to be very close to getting my client speaking with my server by using an SSH tunnel and RMI, but I am getting an exception and i'm not sure why.

Both server and client are using JRE 8, and have a security.policy which grants all permissions (for now). I have tested the server and client when running on the same machine, this works. However, I am now trying to use an SSH tunel to get around a firewall problem.

On the VM which the server runs on, FreeSSHd is installed with port forwarding allowed. On the machine which has the client, I have set up putty with the following settings:

Host: 
Port: 23 (this is set up properly on the router to port forward etc).

Connection/SSH/Tunnels:
Source port: 1099
Destination port: 1099
Dynamic
Auto

When I call Naming.lookup() method on the client side, I get this exception:

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at TMAClient.main(Client.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
HelloClient exception: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
```

The code on the client is like this:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/" + AUTH_OBJECT_BINDING);
```

I think this is probably because of some mistake in the settings in putty, but I am having problems diagnosing what is causing this. I have also tried with a source port of 1098 and destination of 1099, and changing the client to use localhost:1098 but this didn't work.

I know that if I change the port in the naming lookup to something other than 1099 or 1098 (depending how putty is set up), I get a connection refused exception. This suggests that it is connecting, but something is going wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

After adding the VM arguments in the comments as suggested by EJP, I see this when starting up, but i'm  not yet sure if this is important:

```
Jul 10, 2014 9:07:42 AM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: void rebind(java.lang.String, java.rmi.Remote)]
Jul 10, 2014 9:07:42 AM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl[0:0:0, 2]: java.rmi.dgc.Lease dirty(java.rmi.server.ObjID[], long, java.rmi.dgc.Lease)
```

[image: putty tunnel config]
[image: connection]
[image: freeSSH - server side]

Note - I have tried this with and without the forward/bind only to localhost settings.
[image]
[image: connected]

Comment: Can you make it work on your LAN?

Comment: I haven't tried on the lan with tunnelling, unfortunately I only have access to the one VM at the moment on that network. I did however previously have it running over lan but that was without tunnelling, and before I needed to go around any firewalls. I have also installed both rmi-client + rmi-server on the servers VM, and can run that and it works, but that is only local.

Comment: Try the rmi-client from the local machine over the tunnel to the server. EOF suggests something is closing the connection, but there really isn't enough information to diagnose anything here. You could try enabling verbose in putty (if you can). You might also try cygwin, because openssh does have verbose.

Comment: I can't seem to see anywhere to enable "verbose" in putty. I am trying at the moment to connect from the rmi-client over the tunnel to the server, that's what is causing the problem :(. It could potentially be a problem with putty settings / freeSSH that I have set up, but i'm not sure what. I can see that the connection remains open though and isn't closed as I can see the window for it still open and can send commands via SSH

Comment: You don't need a security manager at the client unless the server is using the codebase feature. Run the server JVM with -Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true and -Dsun.rmi.server.exceptionTrace=true so you can see whether you're even connecting to it. See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html) for more things to set: the TCP transport logging could also be useful. Any exceptions of interest, post them here. Edit them into your question.

Comment: With those two JVM arguments set, I see nothing at all on the server side. Other than when starting up the server. I've added this to my question. The server isn't using the codebase feature.

Comment: That means your SSH tunnel isn't set up right yet. Can you post a screenshot of your PUTTY tunnel config screen? NB you can't run it all on a single host, contrary to @ElliotFrisch's apparent suggestion above. You can't have both SSH and RMI listening at he same port in two different processes.

Comment: Thanks EJP, I have attached screenshots of the putty config. I thought whilst I was doing it I should add the FreeSSHd settings on the server side.

Comment: What does D1099 mean? It should mean listen locally at port 1099 and forward to remote port 1099. I can't see that from what you posted.

Comment: D1099 means I had Source port 1099. Destination Port 1099. And in the little radio buttons I ticked "Dynamic" and "Auto". When I click on the D1099 forwarded ports it doesn't re-populate the settings which were entered, but I think that's just a strange putty thing. I can use something other than putty potentially, just as I can change the FreeSSHd on the server if needed

Comment: After reading here: http://serverfault.com/questions/272754/what-is-the-difference-between-local-remote-dynamic-ssh-tunneling I think that should be "local" rather than dynamic. If I change it to Local, i'm now getting a connection refused exception.

Comment: Oh, but this is now from the authenticate method and now from the lookup! One moment, I think this may be the issue with it not using the right port (I can fix that - you mentioned that already).

Comment: @EJP - The answer was two problems. Firstly, it should be local 1099 in putty - you pointed me to question this so thank you. Secondly, the exception thrown with the connection refused exception is because of something you helped me with in another thread but I had not yet propagated all the changes through my code. After fixing the "local" part in putty and the super(1099) to make sure it exports objects correctly.I'll neaten up my question so that it's easier for future users, and if I could give you a hundred upvotes, I would. Thankyou again! If you write your comment as an answer i'll acpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a security manager at the client unless the server is using the codebase feature.

Run the server JVM with

```
-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true
```

and

```
-Dsun.rmi.server.exceptionTrace=true
```

so you can see whether you're even connecting to it. See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html) for more things to set: the TCP transport logging could also be useful. Any exceptions of interest, post them here.

Your SSH tunnel isn't set up right yet. Can you post a screenshot of your PUTTY tunnel config screen? NB you can't run it all on a single host, contrary to @ElliotFrisch's apparent suggestion above. You can't have both SSH and RMI listening at he same port in two different processes.

The PUTTY tunnel should listen locally at port 1099 and forward to remote port 1099. I can't see that from what you posted.